# How can I get my elements to align properly?

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I need help with css in my angular app.

Here's my plunker: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/5GvpLHcGq93yfpqHAJwy?p=preview

But here's the main code snippets as well:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child-component',
  template: `<div class="header">
  <div style="text-align:left;">
      <div class="headerText"> Foo 
        <div style="float:right;">
          <span class="headerText">Language</span>
          <span>
            <select style="margin-right:10px;margin-top:4px;">
              <option *ngFor="let language of languages">{{language}}</option>
            </select>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="headerText"> Bar
          <div style="text-align:-webkit-right; padding-right:10px;">
            <span class="headerText">
              user: admin
            </span>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div style="float:right;">
    <div>
      <button class="signOutButton">Sign Out</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



  `,
  styles: [`.signOutButton {
    background:#5dacb4 !important;
     width:100px;
     height:30px;
     font-size:14px;
     margin:5px;
     float:right;
 }

 .header {
      background:#3f3f3f;
  }

  .headerText {
      color:#ffffff;
      font-size:16px;
      margin-bottom:0px;
      margin-left:10px;
  }`]
})
export class ChildComponent {}
```

The issue I'm having is I need `user:admin` to be on the same line as `Bar`
and the `sign out` button to align all the way right after the `language` and `user` and vertically aligned centered on the right.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something a bit like this?

```css
.signOutButton {
  background:#5dacb4 !important;
  width:100px;
  height:30px;
  font-size:14px;
  position:absolute;
  right:10px;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}

.header {
  background:#3f3f3f;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-size:16px;
  position:relative;
  padding:10px;
}

.left {
  float:left;
}

.right {
  float:right;
}

.line {
  width:calc(100% - 110px);
}
.line::after { /* CLEARFIX */
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

  <div class="line">
    <div class="left">
      Foo
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <select>
        <option>English</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
 
   <div class="line">
    <div class="left">
      Bar
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      user:admin
    </div>
  </div>
 
  <button class="signOutButton">Sign Out</button>
</div>
```

## Explaination

Essentially, with a design like this, the approach that I took was to break it up into two parts: the two "Foo" / "Bar" lines, and the Sign Out button.

Each line needed to have something aligned to it's left, and something aligned to it's right. A normal line of text can't do this, but it is the perfect scenario in which to use `float`!

Unfortunately, floating elements don't take up any space, and since these lines are entirely comprised of floating elements, this means that they themselves don't take up any space. Thankfully, this problem was solved long ago, with a solution commonly known as the [clearfix hack](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/). This is what we use here.

For the Sign Out button, a little absolute positioning is all that we need to pop it in the right place (remember that absolute positioned elements inside elements positioned with `relative` or `absolute` will be positioned relative to that element, not the entire page). However, the lines will overlap with the button. Not good.

Therefore, we simply need to make the lines slightly shorter. How much shorter? I'd say `110px`, as the button is `100px` and it'll look nicer if we leave `10px` of space between the end of the lines and the button, rather than having them pushed up against each other. We can use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to make these lines *exactly* `110px` shorter, by simply having this value subtracted off of `100%`.